# Neo4j Cypher Query to aggregate count of connecting nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have an email graph model located here: http://console.neo4j.org/r/go164n

I am trying to find the count of messages being sent from one email address to another and vice versa.

Basically, there are several email address nodes along with message nodes that connect the email addresses. The relationships between these message and email address nodes are `:SENT or :Received_By`

They can only go one way, so the addresses would be in these formats

- `EmailNode1-[:SENT]->MessageNode1`
- `MessageNode1-[:Received_By]->EmailNode2`

For each message node, there can only be one sender, but multiple receivers are possible.

**What I am trying to get is an aggregate of message counts that are going between two specific email addresses**.

That means in my example, I am trying to get an aggregate of:

`MATCH (n:EmailAddress)-->(m:Message)-->(o:EmailAddress)WHERE n.address='Yoprado@yahoo.com' AND o.address='SammyGee@yahoo.com'WITH n, count(DISTINCT m) AS messageCount, oRETURN n.address, messageCount, o.address`

**AND**

`MATCH (n:EmailAddress)<--(m:Message)<--(o:EmailAddress)WHERE n.address='Yoprado@yahoo.com' AND o.address='SammyGee@yahoo.com'WITH n, count(DISTINCT m) AS messageCount, oRETURN n.address, messageCount, o.address`

Instead of getting two separate counts of the messages going one way or the other, I was wondering if there was a cypher query to automatically sum these counts up

The reason why `MATCH (n:EmailAddress)--(m:Message)--(o:EmailAddress)` won't work is because there may be a third email address node which could potentially send a message to the other two email addresses. This would make both email addresses receivers and I do not want to count these messages.

*Thank you!*

EDIT:

Hey! Actually, I may have confused you. I want the return to be an aggregate of the messages between the two emails. Something that will end up with

n.address           messageCount    o.address
Yoprado@yahoo.com   2               SammyGee@yahoo.com

I can't use MATCH (n:EmailAddress)--(m:Message)--(o:EmailAddress)
because it will also count emails that were sent to both of them but from neither reciever

Comment: Did my edit below solve the problem? It now tallies the number of messages between the nodes.

Answer (score 2):

I think this does what you want:

```
MATCH (n:EmailAddress)-[:SENT]-(m:Message)-[:Received_By]-(o:EmailAddress)
WHERE (n.address='Yoprado@yahoo.com' AND o.address='SammyGee@yahoo.com') 
OR (o.address='Yoprado@yahoo.com' AND n.address='SammyGee@yahoo.com')
WITH n, m, count(DISTINCT m) AS messageCount, o
RETURN n.address, messageCount, o.address, m.body
```

There seems to be an error in your create code too because it creates two separate graphs with the same data. You need parens around the identifiers:

```
CREATE (_6:EmailAddress { address:"Yoprado@yahoo.com" }),
(_7:EmailAddress { address:"SammyGee@yahoo.com" }),
(_8:EmailAddress { address:"Moniqua@yahoo.com" }),
(_9:Message { body:"Sam Sucks" }),
(_10:Message { body:"I suck" }),
(_11:Message { body:"We ALL suck" }),
(_6)-[:SENT]->(_9), 
(_7)-[:SENT]->(_10), 
(_8)-[:SENT]->(_11),
(_9)-[:Received_By]->(_7), 
(_10)-[:Received_By]->(_6), 
(_11)-[:Received_By]->(_6), 
(_11)-[:Received_By]->(_7)
```

It returns the following:

```
n.address           messageCount    o.address               m.body
Yoprado@yahoo.com   1               SammyGee@yahoo.com      Sam Sucks
SammyGee@yahoo.com  1               Yoprado@yahoo.com       I suck

Query took 41 ms and returned 2 rows.
```

---

Edit 1:

If all you want is a count, that simplifies the query:

```
MATCH (n:EmailAddress)-[:SENT]-(m:Message)-[:Received_By]-(o:EmailAddress)
WHERE (n.address='Yoprado@yahoo.com' AND o.address='SammyGee@yahoo.com') 
OR (o.address='Yoprado@yahoo.com' AND n.address='SammyGee@yahoo.com')
RETURN count(*)
```

Comment: please look at my edit above. I may have confused you in what I needed

Comment: @user2819872 I simplified the query to make it return just a count of the emails between the two users. It's not necessary to return the two user emails since you had to specify them in the query to begin with.